# Bean type usage error in authenticationManager in spring boot security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I'm trying to implement custom authentication in spring security, using UserDetails. For that I created my UserDetailsService service:

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Services;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.UserModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.connect.model.UserNotFoundException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UserNotFoundException {
        Optional <UserModel> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            UserModel userModel = optionalUser.get();
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userModel.getUsername(), userModel.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

this is my securityConfig

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Config;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.WebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizeConfig -> {
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/auth").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
                            authorizeConfig.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        })
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

and this is my auth Controller

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.LoginDto;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtAuthenticationResponse;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtTokenProvider;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser (@RequestBody @Valid LoginDto loginDto) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getUsername(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }
}
```

The problem is that when I play my API, the error is returned:

```
Field authenticationManager in com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers.AuthController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

I don't understand why and how I should use a Bean in my application. Can anyone tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthenticationManager` is a container for authentication providers, giving a consistent interface to them all.

Inorder to have AuthenticationManager bean to be in the spring context, you can use the following solution.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
     return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

And you can inject AuthenticationManager wherever you need.

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'getAuthenticationManager' in 'AuthenticationConfiguration'"

Comment: This should be injected into my securityConfig, right?

Comment: Yes ! Thats correct.

Comment: "Cannot resolve method 'getAuthenticationManager' in 'AuthenticationConfiguration'" basically i can't call this method

Comment: There is no such import in this new version apparently